# Creating a group hierarchy in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I can't seem to figure out how to best implement a user model following this schema in Django:

[All are members, some are staff and must be part of a committee, where each committee has a leader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUyoM.png)

I'm creating a custom admin interface for my use. I've extended the `AbstractBaseUser` class to create a new class `User` that represents all members, but there are some fields that are not relevant to members.

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, default='')
    phone_number = models.CharField(default='', blank=True)
    balance = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    minimum_balance = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS, default=STATUS_ACTIVE)
    committee = models.CharField(choices=COMMITTEE, default=COMMITTEE_1)
    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name',
                    'last_name',
                    'email',]

    def get_full_name(self):
        return "{0} {1}".format(self.first_name,self.last_name)

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.first_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

These fields are not needed by a regular member:

```
status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS, default=STATUS_ACTIVE)
committee = models.CharField(choices=COMMITTEE, default=COMMITTEE_1)
```

Should these fields be included in the `User` class and be part of a Group, or should they be somewhere else? How can a leader of a committee be represented in this Django model? Also, is there a better way to implement a hierarchy of users like this in Django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a modal for committee like this.

```
Class Committee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    leader = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Above models depict there will not be multiple committees with the same name, a committee will have some members and one leader.

Comment: Thanks! How would I add a helper method to check if a user is a leader of a committee?